# Why should I use 1bit bitfields instead of bools?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

```
UCLASS(abstract, config=Game, BlueprintType, hidecategories=("Pawn|Character|InternalEvents"))
class ENGINE_API ACharacter : public APawn
{
    GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY() 
...
    UPROPERTY(Transient)
    uint32 bClientWasFalling:1; 

    /** If server disagrees with root motion track position, client has to resimulate root motion from last AckedMove. */
    UPROPERTY(Transient)
    uint32 bClientResimulateRootMotion:1;

    /** Disable simulated gravity (set when character encroaches geometry on client, to keep him from falling through floors) */
    UPROPERTY()
    uint32 bSimGravityDisabled:1;

    /** 
     * Jump key Held Time.
     * This is the time that the player has held the jump key, in seconds.
     */
    UPROPERTY(Transient, BlueprintReadOnly, VisibleInstanceOnly, Category=Character)
    float JumpKeyHoldTime;
```

The code above is from UE4. They seem to use uint32 one bit bitfields instead of bools. Why are they doing this?

Comment: I'd imagine it's to save space.

Comment: `bool` doesn't use one bit, so if they pack more than 4 variables, they gain some space.

Comment: UE4 is a modern engine. Is the memory saving that vital on modern systems?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55262298/advantages-of-boolean-values-to-bit-fields.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A standalone `bool` is at least one byte long. A processor cannot process smaller units. However, we all know that a byte could hold 8 bits/bools, so if you have a data structure featuring multiple bools, you don't need a byte for each. They can share a byte. If you have many of those structures, it may save some memory.

Comment: However accessing bitfields is generally slower, and cannot be done atomically (e.g. for multi-threaded apps)

Comment: That's true. I guess the developer found the benefits more helpful than the disadvantages in this code, maybe somebody else would weight it differently in another piece of code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Atomic bitfield access can be achieved on some architectures. `amd64` may not support this, but `armv6` supports atomic reads.